# Drupal Ubercart product "The requested page could not be found"

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'm doing some maintenance on an old Drupal installation that uses Ubercart for a store.  There's one product page that is giving me `The requested page could not be found.`  This is mystifying me.

I can visit the node itself by using the `/node/###` syntax, and on the settings there I can see the "Url path settings" for the node, but when I try to visit that URL I get the above error.

The one thing that struck me as odd was that in the "Publishing options", the node didn't have "Published" checked off.  So I checked that, saved it...but I still get `The requested page could not be found.`

I'm no Drupal guru, and I want to avoid having to become one.  What could/would be causing this, what things should I check out, what indicators can I check to eliminate different causes?  I'm not shy of digging through log files or rooting around in the database, but I'd like to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have aliases setup for the product/url.  The alias should match the link you are following.